# Can I migrate this old csproj to VS2017 csproj?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, csproj

I want to simplify my PCL csproj and I can't seem to find the appropriate `TargetFrameworks`..

This is my old csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{D035A2E6-EF3E-4F50-B6D7-396F83FE313F}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>PCL.Acme</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>PCL.Acme</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile151</TargetFrameworkProfile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The current nuget has a framework folder formatted like `portable46-net451%2Bwin81%2Bwpa81`.
I cannot target `netstandard1.2` because I have a dependency on another PCL...

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

This csproj format made it possible to reference my old PCL nuget package.
Now I can start migrating the `PCL.Acme.Another.Library` project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.2</TargetFrameworks>
    <PackageId>PCL.Acme</PackageId>
    <Authors>Acme</Authors>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageTargetFallback>
      $(PackageTargetFallback);portable46-net451+win81+wpa81
    </PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="PCL.Acme.Another.Library" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: [there is a tool that converts the csproj files](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017)

Comment: Since the PCL library approach was retired, you now have to pick a `.NETStandard`. If you have any dependency on another PCL, you should have also migrate the dependency to the `.NETStandard` then add that nuget back in. https://montemagno.com/how-to-convert-a-pcl-library-to-net-standard-and-keep-git-history/

Comment: Hi @LeoLiu-MSFT, unfortunately we're talking about a lot of projects that need to migrate to .NetStandard (1.2). Is there an approach to migrate instead of changing everything at once? Maybe have both the PCL and .NetStandard compliant assemblies in 1 package? We currently creating a seperate .NetStandard project where we move all code in to. And then link the files back in the PCL project...? The .NetStandard project is not packaged yet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recreate csproj (start over) with new format it's much easier. This blog post is really helpful https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/

Edit: all supported target frameworks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Edit2:

```
<PackageTargetFallback>
    $(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8
</PackageTargetFallback>
```

Might help as well. More info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj

If link goes down

Class library

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Console app

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Test project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Edit2 does the trick! Now I can top-down support my PCL library nugets and move them to NetStandard one by one. I'll update my question.